# Why are linters not generally used in the python community?

Tags: python, coding-style

It is a very common thing in the javascript community to use linters in order to force contributors to adhere to a specific style guide. I see that as a good thing because that saves time both from the project maintainers and from contributors.

However, although strict style guides apply as well to python projects, no big python projects that I know of use this kind of tool. Why is that?

Edit for clarification: I know there *are* python linters. What I am asking is: why python projects do not generally enforce the use of linters ? Javascript projects normally do.

Comment: I don't know what editor you are using but the editors I use like PyCharm and SublimeText highlight issues that do not conform to PEP-8 standards

Comment: @idjaw It's not that I don't know how to use a linter but why is it that python project do not enforce the use of linters as javascript projects do

Comment: What is your definition of enforcing here? Because I use both languages and The form guidelines are pretty well followed and enforced in the sense of editors giving out warnings and typically code reviewers aware of the guidelines will also mention issues in not following the guidelines

Comment: I mean linters are not integrated in the build/testing process

Comment: Did you notice Jack Evans comments? Pretty good explanations.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of Python linter tools out there, for example: https://github.com/dreadatour/Flake8Lint

There's also the PEP8 style-guide which many developers try to adhere to https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: I know there *are* python linters. I am actually asking why python projects do not enforce them as javascript projects do.

Comment: Because enforcing a strict style guide doesn't always correlate to making code more readable. See [Raymond Hettinger - Beyond PEP 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M).